# how detect form is submitted?

Tags: webforms, forms

I use Drupal 7 and the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.

How can I know if a form is submitted or not? I need this to show either error messages or success message after form submission in form page.

I prefer not to write a module because I think it is unnecessary to write a module for a very small task.

Some more info to further explain my question:

- I already know about the setting for Webform per form. This setting is located "Content > Webforms(tab) > Edit(your form) > Webform(tab) > Form settings" (where you can add the confirmation message or redirect to a Custom URL).
- Actually I render my webform in my `node--contact.tpl.php` and I use the [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module for my form validations. And with the `form_get_errors` function I get errors and loop through them and show them. And if submission is successful I show form successful submission message. I just don't know how to detect whether form is submitted or not.

Comment: *"[If the question is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question.](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"* - If it's submitted, it's submit handler is fired, what's your exact problem with it? And everything you do in Drupal you do using modules, either your own, or contributed by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with drupal_get_messages() function !
the result of this function is different for when form is submitted and also for when form is not submitted.

Answer (score 0):

There a setting for Webform per form. This setting is located "**Content > Webforms(tab) > Edit(your form) > Webform(tab) > Form settings**". You can add the confirmation message or redirect to a Custom URL.

Comment: I already know that actually I render my webform in my node--contact.tpl.php and I use webform validation module for my form validations.and with form_get_errors function I get errors and loop through them and show them. And if submission is successful I show form successful submission message. I just don't know how to detect whether form is submitted or not.

Comment: @majid8911 Any submitted form data should be in "Results" tab

Comment: sorry ! I didn't get you. where is results tab?? 
I'm new to drupal ! sorry if it seems stupid question !
I compared my webform object data after and before submission there wasn't any differences which I can detect form is submitted !

Comment: @majid8911 It located "Content > Webforms(tab) > Edit(your form) > Results(tab)". You can check them under "Submissions" or "Table" section.